# How to export outlook attachment to excel?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I've tried to export an Outlook attachment to Excedl using the following cocde:

```
    Public bCancel As Boolean
    Public dDate As Date
    Public sPath As String

Public Sub TESTMACRO()
    Dim MyOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim MyOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim MySelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim msg As MailItem
    Dim amount As Long

    Set MyOlExp = MyOlApp.ActiveExplorer
    Set MySelection = MyOlExp.Selection

    amount = MySelection.Count

    bCancel = True
    TESTMACROX.Show

    If Not bCancel Then

        If amount = 1 Then

            WaitFinish.Show (False)

            Dim objTesteInforme As New TesteInforme

            objTesteInforme.fecha = dDate
            objTesteInforme.path = sPath

            ' Procesamos el mensaje seleccionado
            If MySelection.Item(1).Class = olMail Then
                ' El objeto seleccionado es un correo
                Set msg = MySelection.Item(1)
                If InStr(1, msg.Subject, "YYYYY") > 0 And InStr(1, msg.Subject, "ZZZZZ") > 0 Then

                    ' Se trata de un mensaje de xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

                    objTesteInforme.CLIENTE = "YYYYYZZZZZ"

                    If (Not objTesteInforme.GeneraTestMacro(msg)) Then
                        ' El procesamiento fracasó
                        MsgBox "El procesamiento del mensaje " & msg.Subject & " fracasó; por favor, revisa el formato del archivo adjunto", vbCritical
                    End If
                                                Else
                                                    MsgBox "El mensaje " & msg.Subject & " no se reconoce como diario Batch de ningún cliente", vbCritical
                                                End If
                End If
                Set msg = Nothing
            Else
                MsgBox "Por favor, selecciona un correo electrónico", vbExclamation
            End If

            WaitFinish.Hide
            Else
                MsgBox "Por favor selecciona uno y solo un mesaje. Gracias", vbExclamation
            End If

        Set MySelection = Nothing
        Set MyOlExp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

The problem is that I select only one message, with the subject YYYYY ZZZZZ - LLLLLLL: 140109, but instead of opening an excel sheet with the attachment it send teh error message "Por favor selecciona uno y solo un mesaje. Gracias". Why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, but I can't translate the spanish methods into english properly (I can't find equivalent of `New TestInforme`).

Based on the error message, it seems that your loop logic is failing.  Try to not use a negative loop.  Something like:

```
...
If bCancel=False then
    ...
Else
    MsgBox 
End If
...
```

Comment: 'TesteInforme' is the name I gave to my workbook (It's a way to refer to objects from Excel)